# Como ejecutar un archivo sql desde Visual Basic script

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

Tengo una consulta realizada en SQLServer 2014 quiero que en VisualBasic Script se ejecute desde un archivo indicándole la ubicación, o en su caso algún código para ejecutarla desde VisualBasic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puede ejecutar secuencias de comandos SQL en el Explorador de soluciones arrastrando un archivo de secuencia de comandos a una base de datos en la carpeta Referencias de base de datos. Otra forma de ejecutar secuencias de comandos SQL es hacer clic con el botón secundario en el script y elegir Ejecutar o Ejecutar en el menú contextual. Cuando elige Ejecutar, la secuencia de comandos SQL se ejecuta en la base de datos predeterminada. Cuando elige Ejecutar en, puede seleccionar qué base de datos utilizar.

Nota Para obtener una lista de las extensiones de archivo de script SQL que puede utilizar, consulte Trabajo con secuencias de comandos.
[Trabajo con secuencias de comandos.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ych5e6t.aspx)

[fuente](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yea4bc1b.aspx)

Espero que sirva.